# Order MySQL query results in DESC order according to another table column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

**Hello !**

**I've two tables in my database**

**table (*orders*)**

```
+--------+----+---------+
|  name  | id | user_id |
+--------+----+---------+
| order1 | 1  | 3       |
| order2 | 2  | 5       |
| order3 | 3  | 5       |
| order4 | 4  | 1       |
| order5 | 5  | 5       |
+--------+----+---------+
```

**table (*reported_orders*)**

```
+----------+---------+------------+
| order_id | user_id | time       |
+----------+---------+------------+
| 2        | 5       | 1535110516 |
+----------+---------+------------+
| 3        | 5       | 1535166516 |
+----------+---------+------------+
| 5        | 5       | 1535168651 |
+----------+---------+------------+
```

**When I execute this query**

```
SELECT name,id FROM orders 
WHERE 
user_id=5
AND 
id IN (SELECT order_id FROM reported_orders WHERE user_id=5 ORDER BY time DESC )
LIMIT 0, 12
```

**I get the result**

```
+--------+----+
|  name  | id |
+--------+----+
| order2 | 2  |
+--------+----+
| order3 | 3  |
+--------+----+
| order5 | 5  |
+--------+----+
```

**but I want to get the result like**

```
+--------+----+
|  name  | id |
+--------+----+
| order5 | 5  |
+--------+----+
| order3 | 3  |
+--------+----+
| order2 | 2  |
+--------+----+
```

**I use `ORDER BY time DESC` in my query to get the results in descending order according to `time` in `reported_orders` table but it doesn't work**

Comment: You can join the tables instead of doing a IN and then you have the time column for ordering

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thnx Join worked with me

Comment: Why are they separate tables?

Comment: @Strawberry Actually ,These tables doesn't exist in my db. I just create examples has similar issue (point) to make the question more simple to read.

Comment: On the evidence provided, the real tables probably shouldn't be separated either!?!?

Comment: [orders] table -In which column (id) is primary key- has the main data of the orders. & [reported_orders] table has the reports data of my app users about these orders. Many users can share the same order , That means > Many users can report the same order with distinct details. So , I've created another table [reported_orders] @Strawberry

Comment: Well, if it was me, I'd construct an example that reflected that reality; it places quite a different complexion on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query worked with me.

```
SELECT orders.name,orders.id, reported_orders.time
FROM orders
INNER JOIN reported_orders
ON (orders.id=reported_orders.order_id) 
WHERE 
(orders.user_id=5 AND reported_orders.user_id=5) 
ORDER BY time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT a.name,a.id FROM orders a join reported_orders b on a.id=b.id where a.user_id=5 and b.user_id=5 order by a.id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
select o.name, o.id from orders o natural join reported_orders ro order by ro.time desc;
```